# oneliner -- multiple file substitution transformation produces out-of-sync results

Tags: perl, substitution

### Context

- perl 5.22
- multi-file transformation with perl oneliner

### Overview

TrevorWattanStewie has a directory full of config files, and he wants to transform them.

The transformation operation is best understood by comparing "BEFORE" to "AFTER".

#### Files BEFORE

```
## ./configfile001.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--

##  ./configfile002.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--

## ./configfile003.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--

## ./configfile004.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--
SallyWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--
RickyWattanStewie@oldmail.com;--blank--
```

#### Files AFTER (Desired result)

```
## ./configfile001.config
TrevorWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile001.config

## ./configfile002.config
TrevorWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile002.config

## ./configfile003.config
TrevorWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile003.config

## ./configfile004.config
TrevorWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile004.config
SallyWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile004.config
RickyWattanStewie@newmail.com;configfile004.config
```

#### Step by Step Explanation

Trevor wants to:

- replace all --blank-- tokens with the name of the file currently being processed.
- change all substrings from `@oldmail` into `@newmail`

### Trevor's attempt

Trevor decides the quickest way to get the job done is with a perl oneliner script.

The oneliner Trevor uses is as follows:

```
perl -pi -e '$curf=$ARGV[0];s/--blank--/$curf/; s/@oldmail.com/@newmail.com/;' *.asc
```

### Problem

When Trevor runs the script, the output does not meet his expectations.

The actual result is as follows:

#### Files AFTER (Actual result)

```
## ./configfile001.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;configfile002.config

## ./configfile002.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;configfile003.config

## ./configfile003.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;configfile004.config

## ./configfile004.config
TrevorWattanStewie@oldmail.com;
SallyWattanStewie@oldmail.com;
RickyWattanStewie@oldmail.com;
```

### Questions

- Why did Trevor's script fail to transform `@oldmail` to `@newmail`?
- Why is the file numbering mismatched? The sequence numbering is off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [variable `$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV), which is the name of the currently processed file.

So `s/--blank--/$ARGV/;`

Also, `@oldmail` (etc) will be interpolated inside the regex, as [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404501/wumpus-q-wumbley) notes.

I always run my one-liners with `-wE`.

Comment: Uggh ... this should have been obvious. Thanks zdim.

Answer (score 2):

Trevor didn't enable warnings, thus missing out on the explanation:

```
$ perl -wpi -e '$curf=$ARGV[0];s/--blank--/$curf/; s/@oldmail.com/@newmail.com/;' *.asc
Possible unintended interpolation of @oldmail in string at -e line 1.
Possible unintended interpolation of @newmail in string at -e line 1.
```

`@oldmail` and `@newmail` are arrays. the `s///` operator interpolates variables, including arrays. You need to use `\@`

Comment: Uggh ... Trevor has been staring at this too long. This should have been obvious. Thanks Wumpus Q. Wumbley.